# ClickOnce manifest error message when published as an offline application

Tags: clickonce

I have a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) project that I want to deploy through [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce). I have set it up to check for updates before launching, no prerequisites to install, and didn't need to modify security settings. I set the application up for offline availability.

I set up [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) and published the application. This succeeded.

I used ClickOnce to install the application to the development server which hosts the application files. This worked fine to install. It brought up the security warning about not verifying publisher information I clicked okay and then my application came up.

I browse from a remote machine to the installer page for my ClickOnce application and click the install button. The dialog window pops up that says "verifying requirements" and then an error pops up that says "Cannot continue this application is improperly formatted" and provides details (see below). I never get the security warning I see when I install it local to the server.

What is strange to me is that if I choose that the application is online as well as offline the ClickOnce install will work and the application will launch. Why won't this work? The deployment is really really simple, just the EXE file and the `exe.config` file. No DLL files or anything like that.

I've now created a clean new project and added in everything and get the same result with ClickOnce deployment. I don't know if this is a configuration issue or a security/access issue.

I can install using ClickOnce to the webserver hosting the files. Any other machine though and it fails to install.

I also set up a new user account, "clickonceuser", and gave them FULL control over the web server's directory. I set up IIS to connect as "clickonceuser" and hit the test button and it verified user and filesystem access was okay.

Error Details:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.225
    System.Deployment.dll         : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.225 (RTMGDR.030319-2200)
    dfdll.dll             : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    dfshim.dll             : 4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url            : http://xxxxxxxxxxx/conveyormerlin/ConveyorMerlin.application

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of http://xxxxxxxxxxx/conveyormerlin/ConveyorMerlin.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Exception reading manifest from http://xxxxxxxxxxx/conveyormerlin/ConveyorMerlin.application: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        + '>' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '"' or '''. Line 1, position 50.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [6/16/2011 9:42:04 AM] : Activation of http://xxxxxxxxxxx/conveyormerlin/ConveyorMerlin.application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [6/16/2011 9:42:05 AM] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestParse)
        - Exception reading manifest from http://xxxxxxxxxxx/conveyormerlin/ConveyorMerlin.application: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirectBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Xml.XmlException
        - '>' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '"' or '''. Line 1, position 50.
        - Source: System.Xml
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
            at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.DtdParserProxy.System.Xml.IDtdParserAdapter.Throw(Exception e)
            at System.Xml.DtdParser.ParseExternalId(Token idTokenType, Token declType, String& publicId, String& systemId)
            at System.Xml.DtdParser.ParseInDocumentDtd(Boolean saveInternalSubset)
            at System.Xml.DtdParser.Parse(Boolean saveInternalSubset)
            at System.Xml.DtdParser.System.Xml.IDtdParser.ParseInternalDtd(IDtdParserAdapter adapter, Boolean saveInternalSubset)
            at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDtd()
            at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDoctypeDecl()
            at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestValidatingReader.XmlFilteredReader.Read()
            at System.Xml.XmlCharCheckingReader.Read()
            at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.Read()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an issue of [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) lookups (deployment provider [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) was a hostname that didn't look up for me), because I wasn't on the same domain as the deploy application. I wish I knew a workaround, but for now I'll deal.